# Como é que a concorrencia optimista funciona?

Tags: banco-de-dados, concorrência

Numa aplicação com concorrencia pessimista há contenção de dados normalmente envolvendo mechanismos de locking. Na concorrencia optimista não. Dois clientes podem tentar escrever mas só um consegue. Quais são as  condições minimas necessárias para implementar uma aplicação de concorrencia optimista? Qual é a diferenca entre concorrencia optimista e "o último a chegar ganha"?